# How can I maintain leading zeros in a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have an array formula as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("NUMBER-"&SEQUENCE(33,16,1,1))
```

The array of numbers from SEQUENCE run from 1 to 528, but I want all the numbers to have matching lengths.

Currently, Google Sheets strips out any leading zeros.

In other words, my formula returns `"NUMBER-1"` to `"NUMBER-528"` but I want it to return `"NUMBER-001"` to `"NUMBER-528"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use TEXT to set the amount of digits:

```
=ArrayFormula("NUMBER-"&TEXT(SEQUENCE(33,16,1,1),"000"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula below is the [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087) approach.  Other approaches using the [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) function such as [@Martín's excellent answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/171115/) have absolutely nothing wrong with them; This approach simply uses the [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087) function.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("NUMBER-"&RIGHT("00"&SEQUENCE(33,16),3))
```

[image]

## Explanation

Within the [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275):

1. A 33x16 array is created using a [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) of numbers, incrementing by `1`, from `1` to `528`.  The function is simplified to `SEQUENCE(33,16)` since the optional arguments already default to `1`.
2. Strings are created by adding leading zeros `"00"` onto each number. For example,
   **`{number:string}` ⇾**  `{1:"001"}` **,**  `{99:"0099"}` **,**  `{511:"00511"}`
3. [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087) is used to return only the last three characters of each string. For example,
   **`{string:RIGHT(string,3)}` ⇾**  `{"001":"001"}` **,**  `{"0099":"099"}` **,**  `{"00511":"511"}`
4. Then `"NUMBER-"` is prepended to each value.

## Functions

- [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087) returns a substring from the end of a specified string.
  `RIGHT(string, [number_of_characters])`
- [SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) returns an array of sequential numbers.
  `SEQUENCE(rows, [columns], [start], [step])`
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) enables the display of values returned from an array formula into multiple rows and/or columns and the use of non-array functions with arrays.
  `ARRAYFORMULA(array_formula)`